# ImportError when running med2image script

Tags: python

I have installed med2image (ver 1.1.1) package
(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/med2image/1.1.1)
with:

```
pip3 install med2image
```

But when I run it,  I receive the following error:

```
med2image -i .\MRI.nii -d out -o image.jpg -s -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "med2image.py", line 29, in
from . import error
ImportError: cannot import name 'error'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I think the '.' in the 'med2image.py' file has be be replaced by the package name ('med2image').  I guess the author tested this package without installing it for a local directory (='.')

Comment: thanks. but I'm new in python. please more explain me this solution.

Comment: If you edit the 'med2image.py' file, you will find 3 'from . import...' lines.  Replace '.' by 'med2image', so it will be 'from med2image import error'.  And the other 2 lines to.

Comment: I do this but still don't work

Comment: I need it. why does not work. please help me

Answer (score 0):

[after replace '.' by 'med2image'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iilcE.jpg)